# Can't run rails "db: create" with remote ip on mysql

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, database-connection

Here is the log

```
Can't connect to MySQL server on 'remote.ip.here.lol' (110)
Couldn't create 'solicit' database. Please check your configuration.
rails aborted!
Mysql2::Error: Can't connect to MySQL server on 'remote.ip.here.lol' (110)
bin/rails:4:in `<main>'
Tasks: TOP => db:create
(See full trace by running task with --trace)
```

my db.yml is like this:

```
default: &default
  adapter: mysql2
  encoding: utf8
  database: db
  host: remote.ip.here.lol
  port: 3306
  username: admin
  password: supressed
  pool: <%= ENV.fetch("RAILS_MAX_THREADS") { 5 } %>
  timeout: 5000

development:
  <<: *default

test:
  <<: *default
```

I don't have any clue of how to start, I recently got hired, my boss told about a gem dotenv-rails but I can't see how it fit to the current issue that I'm curently facing.

Edit: apparently using localhost and local database and user works fine, but not with the remote configuration.

Edit 2: I've created environment variables with dotenv and apparently I only need to fill a .env file with the needed information, it worked.

Comment: Can you ping the remote host? A connection error could mean it's down, or configured to us IPv6. Also, MySQL could just not be running on the remote server; verify that MySQL is installed and running on the remote IP.

Answer (score 0):

You might not have MySQL running on your machine? It seems you are trying to connect to your server but MySQL is not up.